# Generate SPD(Spectral power Distribution) by the UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I have to generate the SPD or the combination of VIBGYOR colors from the UIImage.
It means If take the image from iPhone Camera then it should look like this[image: A cmbination of all colors if phto taken of some fluroscent lamp]

I just want to know that in what way we can capture the Image from iPhone Camera and it will convert to upper image that is just combination of 7 colors.My simple question here is How we can use the iPhone camera as Prism.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Do you also have a question?

Comment: Yes,This is my question.

Comment: A question generally includes a word like 'who','what','when','where' or 'why'. You have provided a statement.

Comment: I just want to know that in what way we can capture the Image from iPhone Camera and it will convert to upper image that is just combination of 7 colors.My simple question here is How we can use the iPhone camera as Prism.